# Apache showing directory structure of public folder of my Rails Application! Why isnt the application Run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have an Ubuntu LTS Lamp Stack 32 Bit with All dependencies installed for running rails applications. I have deployed my rails application using Capistrano. The application goes to the correct directory on my server, and the current folder is added with my application inside it. When I access the public directory of that browser however I just get a directory listing instead of the app running!

To set up my server I used Ryan Bates' tutorial at https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/wiki/Server-Setup.

I correctly ran cap deploy:setup and then cap deploy (As the app has appeared there fine)

I also have run bundle install once deploying the app and have specified a default route in the routes file (Also deleted my index.html in my public folder) To see the apps for yourself please go to http://scottietom.mooo.com/rails

As you can see just the directories.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance. Tom.

Comment: Would you be interested on doing it on Nginx and Unicorn? http://techbot.me/2010/08/deployment-recipes-deploying-monitoring-and-securing-your-rails-application-to-a-clean-ubuntu-10-04-install-using-nginx-and-unicorn/

Comment: Yes this could be a possibility, however I think I am so close with the capistrano. I thought it might be something small that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you do not have the Passenger module enabled. Double check your Apache config to see if this is the case.

Comment: Passenger is fully installed. I have run and included: LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby         In my apache config file.

Comment: check your permissions and multi-views with according to [official docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application)